# How to reset a prop on cancel event?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a list of attachments that a user can manually delete via a click event. There is a problem when the user cancels his edits, the UI still shows an edited list of attachments despite the previous action being canceled. How can I reset the attachments so they revert back to the original listing?

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/embed/revert-attachments-on-edit-cancel-cobmi)  *(click POSTS --> post id --> EDIT THIS POST --> and then delete an attachment --> click CANCEL EDIT and you will see that the attachment you deleted are gone)*

> I am passing props to child component to be edited:

```
<EditPost
        :post="post"
        @update="editPostFormIsVis=false"
        @cancel="editPostFormIsVis = false"
        :attachmentsArray="attachmentsArray"
        @deleteMediaAttachment="removeItem"
      />
    </section>
```

> Child component with the click event that emits data back to parent:

```
<ul>
          <li>Media Attachments
            <ul v-if="attachmentsFileNames && attachmentsFileNames.length">
              <li v-for="(attachmentFileName, index) in attachmentsFileNames" :key="index">
                <a href="
                    #
                  ">{{ attachmentFileName }}</a>&nbsp;
                <button
                  @click.prevent="$emit('deleteMediaAttachment', attachmentFileName)"
                >Delete me!</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

**Anyone have ideas on how to reset my attachmentsArray on cancel?**

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like from the codesandbox that attachments aren't part of the post object you are caching?

Comment: @StephenCollins not sure I follow..

Comment: I was checking out the functionality for your post caching functionality, which works, and comparing it to how you are handling attachment caching

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `created` method of `EditPost` you'll want to add something like:

```
this.cachedAttachmentsArray = Object.assign([], this.attachmentsArray.attachments)
```

and in your `cancelEdit` method add something like:

```
Object.assign(this.attachmentsArray.attachments, this.cachedAttachmentsArray)
```

for a small change to your `EditPost` Component.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks I had originally tried that but didn’t work.

Comment: @redshift when you add the change I posted in this answer - on a fresh copy of your embedded codesandbox - what do you see? I made the above work on a fresh instance of your embedded codesandbox by merely adding those two lines. If you are seeing an issue across posts it's because you need to deeply copy attachments per post - if you want the same attachments to be able to be removed per post. Currently, it looks like you are probably performing shallow copies of those attachments, which is not an issue that local caching in the EditPost could fix directly.

Comment: all you have to do, if indeed the shallow copy from the import of attachments is causing deleting of one attachment to still appear deleted from another post is the issue, is to modify this of the `data` section of `PostDetail`:

      `attachmentsArray: _.cloneDeep(attachments)`